# Align images next to each other

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having trouble getting these two images lined up where I want them - I'm trying to do a grid style-display but for some reason (despite using display: inline) the images are appearing on separate lines.

I tried editing the width of the "figure" element (since I guessed that was what the problem was) but it just shrunk everything down instead of what I wanted - could anyone help me out?

HTML

```
<div id="blade" class="tab-content">
  <div id="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/abi4hJu.png" class="mini-img" />
      <figcaption class="item_price">$17,000</figcaption>
      <span class="item_name">Gomai Blade</span>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IFAtrSy.png" class="mini-img" />
      <figcaption class="item_price">$1,682</figcaption>
      <span class="item_name">Gomai Blade</span>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mini-img {
    width: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.builder {
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}
.builder fieldset {
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.builder fieldset legend {
    text-align: left;
}
.tab-content {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.tab-content #simpleCart_shelfItem {
    display: inline;
}
.tab-content #simpleCart_shelfItem .item_name {
    display: none;
}
.tab-content #simpleCart_shelfItem figure {
    width: auto;
}
```

I was trying to achieve a sort of "caption" effect under each separate image, but I still wanted the images lined up in a sort of "grid" format - I got the first part done (obviously) but it's the second part that's giving me trouble.  I was hoping to avoid using a table, but I'm not sure if that would be more suited for this or not.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2xcr/)

Comment: you can not have 2 of those : `<div id="simpleCart_shelfItem">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same ID for two DIV's which isn't valid HTML.

Can you instead of using percentages for your image tag use pixels instead. I changed the CSS to the below, adding float, and removing the other CSS.

```
.mini-img {
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-content {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
div.simpleCart_shelfItem { 
    float: left; 
}
```

JSFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/g2xcr/1/

Comment: Heh, I'm glad you guys caught that, I wouldn't have noticed that and down the line it would've definitely caused an issue. Either wa adding float: left fixed it up nicely - thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what all that crazy code you've got is, but this is how I would do it. I understand you probably have all those classes for a reason, but could you consider simplifying, it will make your life easier, and make you a better coder.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/abi4hJu.png" class="mini-img" />
  <p>$17 000</p>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IFAtrSy.png" class="mini-img" />
  <p>$3500</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eshellborn/g2xcr/18/